# How to add csrf_token to forms made in custom template tags in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-csrf

I want to write a custom template tag that returns a form. How can I make sure it includes the csrf_token?

Comment: That is almost similar to the way you return forms using views.

Comment: Well when using forms in views I'm adding the csrf_token in the template. But my tag is supposed to return the form already including the <form></form> tags. So how can I render the token and inject it into the return string?

Answer (score 3):

Get `csrf_token` from context and render hidden field with it.

```
hidden_field = format_html(
                "<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{}' />",
                context.get('csrf_token'))
```

See [{% csrf_token %} source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L52) for more details.